Has anyone conducted a double, double-slit experiment but in a specific way described here?
My question is specifically for the case when an observation is made at the first double-slit as to which slit a particle passes through. In this case, the interference pattern is lost and we observe particle effect instead of a wave effect. However, if we introduce another double-slit (aligned exactly to the first one) before the particle hits the detection screen but do not make an observation as to which slit the particle is passing through, do we still see the particle effect?

Why wouldn’t you?

Best to think of the photon as a very small wave in the EM field. It's small (local) so it can act/look like a particle. Never forget to mention the EM field, the EM field of the apparatus considers all electrons/fields especially the excited electron in the source (before emission!) ... the photon is dumb, the EM field  interferes and guides all energy (photons).  There are no photons in the dark bands, only in the light.


... if we introduce another double-slit (aligned exactly to the first one) before the particle hits the detection screen but do not make an observation ...

Your misunderstanding is in thinking that the photons behave like particles rather than waves between the first screen and the second screen. They do not. They only behave like particles at the point when a measurement of their position. In the Copenhagen interpretation of QM this is called "wave function collapse". So there will be wave function collapse at the first screen (because the unblocked slit is essentially measuring each photon's position) and at the detector - but in between each photon acts as a wave and its wave function evolves according to the Schrödinger equation.
If there is only one unblocked slit in the first screen then the photons continue to behave like waves after they pass the first screen but there is no interference between two slits (because only one slit in the first screen is unblocked). The photons now behave like waves that have originated at the single unblocked slit. If you add a second screen with two slits between the first screen and the detector then you get interference between the two slits in the second screen, which you will see when the photons reach the detector.

Thank you for the explanation. I have one follow up question: in the original double-slit experiment where we observe which slit a particle is passing through, why do we not get an interference pattern on the screen as I believe there is some time for the particle to evolve according to the Schrödinger equation before hitting the detection screen?

@amitadhikari Yes, but if we know which slit a photon has passed through then the uncertainty in its position at the slits screen is much smaller than if it could have gone through either slit. So, yes, its wave function will still evolve according to the Schrodinger equation, and there will be a very small diffraction pattern at the detector but this will be much smaller than the interference pattern we see if the photon could have gone through either slit.

Ah, I see your point. Once we know which slit a particle passed through, there is no other source for the the wave then to interfere with.

See:
Double slit experiment. (what does it mean by observing or measuring what the difference?)
I don't understand the 4 downvotes. This is a perfectly acceptable misunderstanding given the fact that many content creators say observing the path causes "particle-like" behavior. That statement is just going to maximize confusion.

I completely agree with you, there is nothing wrong with this question. There are not too many among us to have been born with Feynman's intuitive understanding of quantum mechanics, and he even said that he did not...

Thank you for correcting my misunderstanding!
